# My text in my clock python is not aligning properly

Tags: python, text, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

My text in my turtle module is not aligning properly, it is aligned up and to the left. I want it to align exactly where the turtle is. Can anyone help? I tried setting the xcor and ycor of the turtle up and to the left by 5 units and that did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime,date
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()

while True:
    turtle.tracer(0, 0)
    hour_hand = float(datetime.today().hour)
    minute_hand = float(datetime.today().minute)
    second_hand = float(datetime.today().second)

    # Draw circle
    t.hideturtle()
    t.circle(150)
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.forward(150)
    t.down()

    # Draw hands
    t.right(float(float(minute_hand) * 6))
    t.forward(100)
    t.backward(100)
    t.left(float(float(minute_hand) * 6))
    t.right(int(float(hour_hand) * 30 + float(minute_hand) / 60 * 30))
    t.forward(50)
    t.backward(50)
    t.left(int(float(hour_hand) * 30 + float(minute_hand) / 60 * 30))
    t.right(second_hand * 6)
    t.forward(125)
    t.backward(125)
    t.left(second_hand * 6)

    # Draw ticks
    for x in range(0, 12):
        t.up()
        t.forward(130)
        t.down()
        t.forward(20)
        t.backward(20)
        t.up()
        t.backward(130)
        t.down()
        t.right(30)
    for y in range(0, 60):
        t.up()
        t.forward(140)
        t.down()
        t.forward(10)
        t.backward(10)
        t.up()
        t.backward(140)
        t.down()
        t.right(6)
    t.up()

    # Draw numbers
    t.right(32.5)
    for z in range(1, 12):
        t.forward(130)
        t.sety(t.ycor() - 5)
        t.setx(t.xcor() - 5)
        t.write(z, align = 'center', font = ('Times New Roman', 16))
        t.sety(t.ycor() + 5)
        t.setx(t.xcor() + 5)
        t.backward(130)
        t.right(30)
    t.forward(130)
    t.write(12, align = 'center', font = ('Times New Roman', 16))
    turtle.update()
    t.hideturtle()
    time.sleep(0.85)
    t.reset()
```

I don't really want to use tkinter, it is too complicated.

Comment: Bro i put your code in pycharm and I got no error it works perfectly fine.......

Comment: @harshjain I wasn't saying there was an error with my code, I'm asking about why the text is not aligning properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler, though potentially less accurate, way to do this completely within turtle:

```
FONT_SIZE = 16
FONT = ('Times New Roman', FONT_SIZE)

t.color('red')
t.dot(2) # show target of where we want to center text, for debugging
t.color('black')

t.sety(t.ycor() - FONT_SIZE/2)
t.write(12, align='center', font=FONT)
```

[image]

Now let's address your program as a whole.  The primary issues I see is that it flickers and is more complicated than necessary.  The first thing to do is to switch turtle into *Logo* mode, which makes positive angles clockwise and makes 0 degrees at the top (not unlike a clock!).

Then we split the dial drawing onto it's own turtle to be drawn *once* an we put the hands on their own turtle to be erased and redraw over and over.  We all toss the `while True:` and `sleep()`, which have no place in an event-driven world like turtle, and use a turtle timer event instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

OUTER_RADIUS = 150
LARGE_TICK = 20
SMALL_TICK = 10

FONT_SIZE = 16
FONT = ('Times New Roman', FONT_SIZE)

def draw_dial():
    dial = Turtle()
    dial.hideturtle()

    dial.dot()

    dial.up()
    dial.forward(OUTER_RADIUS)
    dial.right(90)
    dial.down()
    dial.circle(-OUTER_RADIUS)
    dial.up()
    dial.left(90)
    dial.backward(OUTER_RADIUS)

    for mark in range(60):
        distance = LARGE_TICK if mark % 5 == 0 else SMALL_TICK
        dial.forward(OUTER_RADIUS)
        dial.down()
        dial.backward(distance)
        dial.up()
        dial.backward(OUTER_RADIUS - distance)
        dial.right(6)

    dial.sety(-FONT_SIZE/2)
    dial.setheading(30)  # starting at 1 o'clock

    for z in range(1, 13):
        dial.forward(OUTER_RADIUS - (LARGE_TICK + FONT_SIZE/2))
        dial.write(z, align='center', font=FONT)
        dial.backward(OUTER_RADIUS - (LARGE_TICK + FONT_SIZE/2))
        dial.right(30)

def tick():
    hour_hand = datetime.today().hour
    minute_hand = datetime.today().minute
    second_hand = datetime.today().second

    hands.reset()
    hands.hideturtle()  # redo as undone by reset()

    hands.right(hour_hand * 30 + minute_hand / 60 * 30)
    hands.forward(1/3 * OUTER_RADIUS)
    hands.backward(1/3 * OUTER_RADIUS)
    hands.left(hour_hand * 30 + minute_hand / 60 * 30)

    hands.right(minute_hand * 6)
    hands.forward(2/3 * OUTER_RADIUS)
    hands.backward(2/3 * OUTER_RADIUS)
    hands.left(minute_hand * 6)

    hands.right(second_hand * 6)
    hands.forward(OUTER_RADIUS - (LARGE_TICK + FONT_SIZE))
    hands.backward(OUTER_RADIUS - (LARGE_TICK + FONT_SIZE))
    hands.left(second_hand * 6)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')  # make 0 degrees straight up, positive angles clockwise (like a clock!)
screen.tracer(False)

draw_dial()

hands = Turtle()

tick()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: result will depend heavily on your environment https://i.imgur.com/1YEivzi.png

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534, surprisingly so!  I'll need to consider using your approach going forward (+1).

Comment: My visual studio environment makes it a tiny bit off, but it will do.

Comment: Would you mind if you edit your post to move the turtle text a bit down cdlane? I would appreciate that.

Comment: And please clarify what is doing what in your tick() function.

Comment: @EnderRamsby, my `tick()` function consists of code directly from your original with symbols instead of numbers.  The only significant difference is the `screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)` call which instead of `sleep()` tells turtle to call this function again in 1 second (1000 milliseconds.)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't really want to use tkinter, it is too complicated.

I don't think it's too complicated and it is the most straight-forward solution to center the text vertically.

Use the following code to get the height of text in your font:

```
from tkinter import font

t = turtle.Pen()

font_config = font.Font(font=('Times New Roman', 16))
font_height = font_config.metrics("linespace")
```

Then draw your text using `font_height/2` as the vertical offset:

```
        t.sety(t.ycor() - font_height/2)
        t.write(z, align="center", font=font_config)
        t.sety(t.ycor() + font_height/2)
```

Comment: I can use tkinter but I don't want to

Comment: @EnderRamsby, what's going unsaid is that turtle is implemented atop tkinter.  Anytime there's a low level feature of tkinter that turtle doesn't expose, dropping down to the tkinter level is an option.