# How to make font change its size to fit in the window using turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I wrote code with Python's turtle module to display text in a 600x600 window.

```
import turtle
import tkinter
win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("test")
win.bgcolor("white")
win.setup(width=600, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

pen1 = turtle.Turtle()
pen1.speed(0)
pen1.shape("square")
pen1.color("black")
pen1.penup()
pen1.hideturtle()
pen1.goto(-2, -2)
pen1.color("black")
pen1.write("test", align="center", font=("Helvetica Narrow", 68, "bold"))
while True:
    win.update()
```

It works, but I want it to change the font size when it doesn't fit the window.
When I use small words like "test", it works:

[image: yes]

But when I use large words it overflows like this:

[image: yes2]

Is there any way I can make so that it automatically changes the font size to fit the window?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by:

- Setting up a function that calculates the intended font size based on text to be shown and the width of the window
- Passing that font size to another function that erases and re-writes the message at every update with the intended font size and the message.

Code for that implementation is below. I doubt that the `while True: update` approach to screen refresh is robust enough for many things beyond showing some text on the screen, however.

```
import turtle as t

win = t.Screen()
win.title("test")
win.bgcolor("white")
win.setup(width=600, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

pen1 = t.Turtle() # define the pen turtle to be globally accessible
pen1.speed(0)
pen1.shape("square")
pen1.color("black")

def write_text(text):
    pen1.clear() # clear previously written text
    pen1.penup()
    pen1.hideturtle()
    pen1.goto(-2, -2)
    font_size = scale_font(text) # calculate the fitting font size
    pen1.write(text, align="center", font=("Helvetica Narrow", font_size , "bold"))

def scale_font(text):
    font_size = int(win.window_width()/len(text)) # use window width and length of text to calculate font size
    return font_size

while True:
    write_text("hi there")  # continuously rewrite the message at every update
    win.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does what you describe.  It pulls in the tkinter font interface a la this [earlier post about vertically centering fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119667/5771269).  I only adjust the font size based on width -- if you need to also adjust based on height, you'll need to add to the code.  Just run it, sit back, and watch:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from tkinter import font

FONT_FAMILY = "Helvetica Narrow"
FONT_SIZE_ESTIMATE = 60

# from https://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Diamante-Poem
lines = [
    "Summer",
    "Warm, bright",
    "Laughing, running, playing",
    "A time to be outside and feel the sun",
    "Enjoying, swimming, eating",
    "Peaceful, nice",
    "Heat",
]

font_size = FONT_SIZE_ESTIMATE

def display():
    global font_size

    text = lines.pop(0)

    while True:
        font_config = font.Font(font=(FONT_FAMILY, font_size))
        width = font_config.measure(text)

        if width > window_width * 0.9:
            font_size -= 1
        elif width < window_width * 0.8:
            font_size += 1
        else:
            break

    offset = font_config.metrics('ascent') / 2
    pen.sety(-offset)
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(text, align="center", font=font_config)

    if lines:
        screen.ontimer(display, 1500)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)

window_width = screen.window_width()

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.penup()

display()

screen.exitonclick()
```