# Labeling a game board in python using turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm currently making a 5x5 grid for a snakes and ladder but can't figure out how to display the numbers on the grid in this formation;

```
21,22,23,24,25
                               
20,19,18,17,16
                               
11,12,13,14,15
                               
10, 9, 8, 7, 6
                               
1 , 2, 3, 4, 5
```

The code I've wrote makes the 5x5 grid, I'm juts note sure how to add the labels of if I should take a
different approach with the code.

thanks for any help.

```
import turtle 

    t = turtle.Turtle()
    speed = turtle.speed()

    t.speed(10)
    x=250
    y=250
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-x,y)
    t.pendown()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.ht()
    for a in range(5):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(-x,-y)
        t.pendown()
        y=y-100

        for b in range(5):
            for n in range(5):
                t.speed(10)
                t.fd(100)
                if n!=4:
                    t.right(90) here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses much of your existing logic, tweaking it a bit, and adds the numbers:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')

BOXES = 5
BOX_SIZE = 100

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

x = -BOX_SIZE * BOXES / 2
y = -BOX_SIZE * BOXES / 2

for i in range(BOXES):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    for j in range(BOXES):
        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(BOX_SIZE)
            turtle.left(90)

        dx, dy = turtle.position()

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(dx + BOX_SIZE/2, dy + BOX_SIZE/2 - FONT_SIZE / 2)
        turtle.write(j + BOXES * i + 1, align='center', font=FONT)
        turtle.setposition(dx, dy)
        turtle.pendown()

        turtle.forward(BOX_SIZE)

    y += BOX_SIZE

screen.exitonclick()
```

Centering-wise, the vertical font correction (`FONT_SIZE / 2`) is an approximation that works fine on my system but if you want an accurate solution for all systems, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119667/5771269)

[image]